# Transform bug on Firefox (animation)

Tags: html, css, animation, transform, translate-animation

I have one strange bug on whole site, when I add animation for elements (only on Firefox). Sometimes elements duplicate, but when I open inspector they disappear.
My code (I have auto prefixes):

```
.animated {
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
@keyframes slideInUp {
  from {
    transform: translateY(70px);
    visibility: visible;
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Add `-moz-` prefix for` keyframes` and `transform` properties.

Comment: Could you recreate your example using a code snippet or codepen/jsfiddle ? Is it working correctly on IE, Edge, Chrome, etc. ?

Comment: @AnureshVP I have auto prefixes library (I have -moz- prefix in css file, but it doesn't help)

Comment: @Jake I use only this transform properties for animation and it's work in all browsers and have this bug only in Firefox

Comment: @EmilyHarkness Do you have a fiddle or codepen?

Comment: @Emily Harkness can we get the website URL atleast?